# How to use Unsupported Locales in java.text.DateFormat

Tags: java, date, locale, date-format

I am trying to get the date format for Pakistan locale "en_PK" which is ""dd/MM/yy"

```
Locale localePK = new Locale("en", "PK");
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, localePK);
```

The above snippet returns "MM/dd/yy"

But the locale seems to be unsupported and not available in the `DateFormat.getAvailableLocales()` List.

Please suggest an ideal way to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could write a wrapper class that returns a formatted date.  Use the Locale when it's available and use a specific DateTimeFormatter when the Locale is absent.

Comment: Reopened it as the problem that OP has mentioned is how to find `Pakistan`'s locale from `DateFormat.getAvailableLocales()` List.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the country name using the `Locale` object while navigating `DateFormat.getAvailableLocales()` and break the loop once you've found it.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.chrono.IsoChronology;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale localePk = null;
        for (Locale locale : DateFormat.getAvailableLocales()) {
            if (locale.getDisplayCountry().equals("Pakistan")) {
                localePk = locale;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (localePk != null) {
            String datePattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.SHORT, null,
                    IsoChronology.INSTANCE, localePk);
            System.out.println(LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern, localePk)));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
10/10/2020
```

Note that `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` is part of [the modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

If you are doing it for your Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

`java.util` date-time classes are outdated and error-prone and so is their formatting API, `DateFormat`. However, if you are still looking for a solution using these legacy APIs, given below is one:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale localePk = null;
        for (Locale locale : DateFormat.getAvailableLocales()) {
            if (locale.getDisplayCountry().equals("Pakistan")) {
                localePk = locale;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (localePk != null) {
            DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, localePk);
            System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
10/10/2020
```